# Variable value is not being passed inside the function

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, jqlite

I have function, that doesn't work properly for some reason. In my AngularJS app I need to manipulate CSS with jqLite.

Let's say there are two div's and first one has certain width.

```
<div class="primary-item"></div>
<div class="secondary-item"></div>
```

I want to set secondary item width to be the same as primary.

Everything goes fine till the point when function changes CSS. Looks like `widthToSet` value didn't pass there.

```
secondaryItem.css({width: + widthToSet + 'px', height: '100px'});
```

Please see the code in the snippet below.

```js
function changeCss() {
    var masterItem = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.primary-item' ) );
    var widthToSet = angular.element( masterItem.prop('offsetWidth') );
    alert("width to set is" + widthToSet);
    var secondaryItem = angular.element( document.querySelector('.secondary-item') );
    secondaryItem.css({width: + widthToSet + 'px', height: '100px'}); /*width is not being set*/
    //secondaryItem.css({width: '300px', height: '100px'}); /*works fine*/
}

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  changeCss();
});
```

```css
.primary-item {border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px;}
.secondary-item {border: 1px solid green; padding: 10px;}
.primary-item, .secondary-item {float: left; clear: both; margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="primary-item">Some content here</div>
<div class="secondary-item"></div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is `document.querySelector('.primary-item')` returning anything?

Comment: what's the result of `+ widthToSet + 'px'` ?

Comment: @JeffWatkins that's not an issue. Using the unary operator before a string value is equivalent to passing it through `Number()`: http://jsfiddle.net/dmo2ggo1/

Comment: `var widthToSet = masterItem.prop('offsetWidth');`

Comment: @Hacketo thank you!I was just overcomplicating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hacketo for help.

The problem was in declaration of `widthToSet` variable.

```js
function changeCss() {
    var masterItem = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.primary-item' ) );
    var widthToSet = masterItem.prop('offsetWidth');
    var secondaryItem = angular.element( document.querySelector('.secondary-item') );
    secondaryItem.css({width: + widthToSet + 'px', height: '100px'}); 
}

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  changeCss();
});
```

```css
.primary-item {border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px;}
.secondary-item {border: 1px solid green;}
.primary-item, .secondary-item {float: left; clear: both; margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="primary-item">Some content here</div>
<div class="secondary-item"></div>
```